# It has become impossible to meet the team building Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design

After the redesign of `stackoverflow.com/company/*` pages the [Team page](https://stackoverflow.com/company/team) became an orphan: it is not linked from anywhere under `/company/`. The page has navigation tabs that lead elsewhere, but there is no "team" in tabs.

[image: there is no "team" in tabs]

Comment: I guess that's one way to tell people they're being let go...

Comment: No, no, no, you're confused. It goes "There's no I in 'team'".

Comment: What a bitter, bitter irony it is that someone finally wants to meet me, but the only way they once could have is offline. I had a *lot* of dreams like this in Junior High School.

Comment: So seems to have an awfully small "IT" team...I mean "marketing" is twice as big, you've changed guys!! ;)

Comment: I mean I've never noticed this page before now, it's not something I think I'm going to miss...

Comment: JEEZ, you seen the size of "Sales - Talent" No wonder you added that new recruitment thingy, those people have kids to feed. #mindblown

Comment: Woah what a smooth circle! Me thinks you have a stylus #sneaky

Comment: Wait a minute.... I thought SO was a one-man show? /s

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It's being redesigned to something easier for the People team here to manage. The short version of the story is that we're now at the company size where a wall of faces doesn't really work that well anymore.

I don't know exactly what the plan is there, but the first stage of it was to keep the page accessible but not lead people to it anymore. Once the redesign is complete, the tab will return.

Comment: People team, or Team people?

Comment: @TinyGiant Yes.

Comment: @TinyGiant: The Team team, staffed by People people, who are also people people.

Comment: @NathanTuggy To be clear, the people team is teeming with team people.

Comment: Hmm, I've heard of this before. The company gets so awesome that it rocks everyone's faces off.

Comment: People teams are not usually as technical as the technical team for some odd reason, but they might have other skills with this "people" part, have to ask a people person.  Where do I post that question?